# Ext JS 4.2.1 check username availibility best practive

Tags: javascript, asp.net-web-api, httprequest, extjs4.2

i am developing an application with ExtJS 4.2.1 and a .NET Web API backend...

When i create i new user through the gui i add it to my store and sync it afterwards...
something like this

this is a snippet from my alter-user-window

```
window.on('save', function(win) {            
            this.getForm().updateRecord(this.getUser());
            if (!this.getUser().validate().isValid()) {
                this.getForm().markInvalid(this.getUser().validate().items);
                return;   
            }            

            if (win.getType() == 'new') {                
                userController.addUserToStore(this.getUser());                
            }

            userController.syncUserStore();

        }, this);
```

In my userstore i wont have all users loaded every time. So i need to check the availability of the username on the server anyway..

My questions:

1. should i make an additional request to check the username availability or should i just send an other response from the server when i do want to save the user ???
2. what should the response look like if the username is not valid? should i send and ErrorResponseCode like 409 Conflict or something or should i send just a 200 OK Response with a special response message??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Completely depends on you. Both options are OK.
2. Returning 409 is a good idea. [HTTP Status 409](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E409.html) is meant to be used for returning application-specific conflict error.